# Using 'WHERE' with user-defined variable

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm fairly new to SQL, and I'm trying save myself some time searching for a single value across multiple columns, so that I don't have to paste the value into 3 quotes.

EG:

```
SET @u1 := '000123';

SELECT * FROM database1.table1
WHERE id = @u1
OR prev_id = @u1
OR next_id = @u1
OR link_id = @u1
;
```

So in the above scenario, I'm trying to find where the id=000123 is either the id, prev_id, next_uid, link_uid, rather than having to paste 4 instances in the following:

```
SELECT * FROM database1.table1
WHERE id LIKE '000123'
OR prev_id = '000123'
OR next_id = '000123'
OR link_id = '000123'
;
```

Looking around, I'm fairly sure that this is possible, but perhaps I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
SELECT *
FROM database1.table1
WHERE  @u1 in (id, prev_id, next_id, link_id);
```

Comment: It may well be, but I'm receiving the following error message:
Error Code: 1270. Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT), (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT), (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation ' IN '

Comment: It sounds like the default database collation is different from the table collation.  You can use the COLLATE key work to change collations.